# How can I remove quotes from a string that is used in an attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

It's the first time i'm using xlst langage.
I have a little problem but i can't find the solution.

Example of XML :

```
<DATA>
    <KEY>1234</KEY>
    <VALUE>"AB"</VALUE>
</DATA>
<DATA>
    <CLE>4567</CLE>
    <VALUE>"CD"</VALUE>
</DATA>
```

I'm building an input xml like that :

```
 <TestAlias Alias="{DATA[1]/KEY}" ExtRef="{DATA[1]/VALUE}"/>
```

the result is almost perfect :

```
<ProjectAlias Alias="1234" ExtRef="**&#34**;AB**&#34**;"/>
```

The problem is the " "on my VALUE. Can I chose to not take them when i do `ExtRef="{DATA[1]/VALUE}"` ?

Comment: You can use `translate()` to remove **all** quotes, or `substring()` to skip the first and last character. One example is not sufficient to tell what's best.

Comment: I have to create a <xsl:variable name="variable1"/> put my ExtRef and then make a substring/translate or i can do it directly with my ExtRef ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one of these will work with your example:

**1.**

```
<TestAlias Alias="{DATA[1]/KEY}" ExtRef="{translate(DATA[1]/VALUE, '&quot;', '')}"/>
```

will remove **all** quotes;

**2.**

```
<TestAlias Alias="{DATA[1]/KEY}" ExtRef="{substring(DATA[1]/VALUE, 2, string-length(DATA[1]/VALUE) - 2)}"/>
```

or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:variable name="ext-ref" select="DATA[1]/VALUE" />
<TestAlias Alias="{DATA[1]/KEY}" ExtRef="{substring($ext-ref, 2, string-length($ext-ref) - 2)}"/>
```

will skip the first and the last character.